# ghostscript shrinking pdf doesn't work anymore

Tags: pdf, resize, ocr, tesseract, ghostscript

first question here.

So i was using the ghostscript command to shrink my pdf which yieled good results (around 30-40% decrease in size). However, one day last week it stopped shrinking them and instead returned me a pdf of the size or even a bit heavier (around 1% or less). Therefore I don't know what's going on since the command used to work fine and i was able to shrink some pdf easily...

I will note that when using gs on my pdfs it always return an error about some glyphs missing in the GlyphLessFont but i don't think it's related to my issue (though if you could redirect me to fixing the glyphlessfont that would be much appreciated).

Here's the command I use :

```
`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=out.pdf`
```

Here's also a pdf sample that was shrinked correctly (original file size 4.7mo / shrinked version 2.9mo) https://nofile.io/f/39Skta4n25R/bulletin1_ocr.pdf

EDIT: light version that worked for the file above : https://nofile.io/f/QOKfG34d5Cg/bulletin1_light.pdf

Here's the input and output file of another pdf that didn't work 
(input) https://nofile.io/f/sXsU0Mcv35A/bulletin15_ocr.pdf
(output through the gs command above) https://nofile.io/f/STdJYqqt6Fq/out.pdf

you'll notice that both input and output file are 27.6mo whereas the first file was reduced.

I would also add that i've performed OCR on these pdf using pdfocr and the tesseract engine and that's why i didn't try to convert to png to reduce the size, i need the extra OCR layer so that we can publish those file for our website and we want them to be lighter if possible.

Final info : ghostscript -v is 9.10 (2013-08-30) and tesseract is 3.03 with leptonica-1.70 and pdfocr is 0.1.4

Hope you guys can help !

EDIT2: while waiting for the answer I continued my scanning and ocring of the documents and it appears that after passing my pdf through pdfocr it was shrinked like it used to with the ghostscript. Therefore i wonder if the script pdfocr does the shrinking with ghostscript since i know it invokes it for other tasks during the process of OCRisation.

Answer (score 2):

The PDF has a media size of 35.44 by 50.11 inches, is that really the size of the original ?

Given that you appear to commonly use OCR I assume that, in general, your PDF files simply consist of very large images. In that case the major impact on the file size is going to come from downsampling the images. If you look at the [documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/VectorDevices.htm#COMMON) you can see that the /screen settings downsample images to 72 dpi, with a threshold of 1.5 (so images over 72 * 1.5 = 107 dpi will be downsampled to 72, anything less is regarded as not worth it)

Your PDF file has a media size of 35.44 x 50.11 inches. Its rather a large file (26 pages) so I'll limit myself to considering page 1. On this page there is one image, and a bunch of invisible text, placed there by Tesseract. The image on page 1 is a 8-bit RGB image with dimensions 2481x3508, and it covers the entire page.

So the resolution of that image is 2481 / 35.44 by 3500 / 50.11 = 70.00 x 69.84

Since that is less than 72 dpi, pdfwrite isn't going to downsample it.

Had your media been 8.5 x 11 inches then the image would have had an effective resolution of 2481 / 8.5 by 2500 / 11 = 291.8 x 318.18 and so would have been downsampled by a factor of about 4.

However..... for me your 'working' PDF file also has a large media size, and the images are also already below the downsampling resolution. When I run that file using your command line, the output file is essentially the same size as the input file.

So I'm at a loss to see how you could ever have experienced the reduced file size. Perhaps you could post the reduced file as well.

**EDIT**

So, the reason that your files are smaller after passing through Ghostscript is because the vast majority of the content is the scanned pages. These are stored in the PDF file as DCT encoded images (JPEG).

The resolution of the images is low enough (see above) that they are not downsampled. However, the way that old versions of Ghostscript work is that image data  is always decompressed on reading, and then recompressed when writing.

Because JPEG is a lossy image format, this means that the decompressed and recompressed image is of lower quality than the original, and the way that loss of quality is applied means that the data compresses better.

So a quirk of the way that Ghostscript works results in you losing quality, but getting smaller files. Note that for current versions of Ghostscript, the JPEG data is passed through unchanged, **unless** your configuration requires it to be donwsampled, or colour converted.

So why doesn't it compress the other file ? Well for current code, of course, which is what I'm using, it won't, because the image doesn't need downsampling or anything.

Now, when I run it through an old version of Ghostscript which I have here (9.10, chosen because that's what your working reduced file is using) then I do indeed see the file size reduced. It goes down from 26MB to 15MB.

When I look at your 'not working' reduced file, I see that **it** has been produced by Ghostscript 9.23, not Ghostscript 9.10.

So the reason you see a difference in behaviour is because you have upgraded to a newer version of Ghostscript which does a better job of preserving the image data unchanged.

If you really want to reduce the quality of the images you can set `-dPassThroughJPEGImages=false` but IMO you'd do better to either get the media size of the original PDF coreect (surely the pages are not really 35x50 inches ?) or set the ColorImageResolution to a lower value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Well my pdfs look pretty much the same, it's like the annual report of an association and their title page are somewhat always that. 
So that might be the case for the first page. However what interests me if more the reducing of the text pages which are the rest of the documents, i'll include my working pdf now. Also i have noted that (i am continuing the scanning/ocring of the pdfs) and now my pdfs after having being ocered are reduced with the ocr layer still intact which baffles me quite a bit....

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your helpful comment ! You saved me :)